# How can I migrate test cases with shared steps from TFS to Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure, testing, tfs, azure-devops, testcase

How can I migrate test cases with shared steps and shared parameters from TFS to Azure DevOps? I could migrate test cases but they didn't include the shared steps and shared parameters.

Answer (score 0):

User this tool: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nkdagility.vsts-sync-migration

In the configuration.json file update below code, it will migrate test cases along with Shared steps and shared parameters

"WIQLQueryBit": "AND  [Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ClosedDate] = '' AND [System.WorkItemType] IN ('Test Case','Test Suite','Shared Steps','Shared Parameter')",

Answer (score -1):

There are different work item types: *Test case*, *Shared Steps* and *Shared Parameter*. You could [export them to CSV files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/import-work-items-from-csv?view=azure-devops#export-list-as-csv) separately, and then [import](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/import-work-items-from-csv?view=azure-devops#import-new-work-items) them to Azure DevOps projects.
[image]
**update>>** If your test case adds shared steps, export it to csv from a query containing steps column, you will find that steps contains section like `<compref id="2" ref="734">`, the 734 is the id of shared steps in this project.

Therefore, if you import shared steps to Azure DevOps project, the shared steps will own a new id, you need to edit the csv file to update the id of shared steps, and then import it to Azure DevOps project can find this previously imported shared steps.

Comment: Thank you Edward but how to map the test cases and their shared steps/parameters in Azure?

Comment: I have updated my answer, please check it and kindly let know the result.

Comment: I have exported the test cases along with their shared steps from TFS into a CSV file and tried to import the results in Azure. Unfortunately, the import does not work successfully as the Azure import template splits "steps" column into: Test Step, Step action and Step Expected. Besides, there is no way to map the shared steps with the extracted test cases. Please note that I 'am trying to migrate bulk work items from TFS to Azure.

Answer (score -1):

Found this GitHub thread: https://github.com/nkdAgility/azure-devops-migration-tools/issues/518, which sharing one [workaround](https://github.com/nkdAgility/azure-devops-migration-tools/issues/518#issuecomment-690945677) as following.

- import all work items except shared steps, shared parameter, test plans and test suites. (Custom reference)
- run a script on test cases to mirror the custom reference field to integration build
- import shared steps, shared parameter and test cases(integration build)
- finally, import test suites using the test migration method.

Comment: Hi ammarov, Does my answer help? Please check it and kindly let us know the result.